# React Native Firebase How To Have Auto Document Id Increment by 1

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I would simply like to have auto increment. Currently whatever I create in my app that document in firebase gets automatic big random id. I would like for each new document inside collection to simply have 1+ id, for example I mean first document inside collection gets id = 1, second document will automatically get id=2 and so on... here is my code of for example creating a post:

```
addPost = async ({ text, avatar, name }) => {

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      this.firestore
        .collection("posts")
        .add({
          text,
          //text2,
          //id,
          uid: this.uid,
          timestamp: this.timestamp,
          avatar,
          name,
        })
        .then((ref) => {
          ref.update({ id: ref.id });
          res(ref);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          rej(error);
        });
    });
  };
```

Comment: What you're describing is not the way that Firestore works.  It doesn't provide incremental IDs for either documents for fields.  These sort of things don't scale the way that Firestore requires.  You can implement a counter in a separate document on your own if you don't need Firestore's default scalability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HOW I SOLVED THIS: I CREATED A NEW COLLECTION CALLED "id" and gave it only one field called also "id" and of type number. I put value of 0. The secret is to get this value in a state, and increment it every time I make a new post(aka every time I want to icnrement my id in some other collection). Then for the id I want incremented in my other collection i use that state and put +1. Complicated, but for anybody who needs it here is the code:

```
addPost = async ({ text, avatar, name }) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      this.provjera();

      this.firestore
        .collection("posts")
        .add({
          text,
          id: this.state.specialid + 1,
          uid: this.uid,
          timestamp: this.timestamp,
          avatar,
          name,
        })
        .then((ref) => {
          
          console.log(this.state.specialid);
          this.setState({ specialid: this.state.specialid + 1 });
          this.firestore
            .collection("id")
            .doc("hl6ucFvzQ18lIFae9feo")
            .update({ id: this.state.specialid });
          //console.log(this.state.specialid);
          res(ref);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          rej(error);
        });
    });
  };
```

and here is check method:

```
check = async () => {
    const yolo = [];
    const snapshot = await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("id")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          const { id } = doc.data();
          yolo.push({ id: id });
          this.setState({ specialid: yolo[0].id });  //this gets field value of id inside collection id which is 0.
        });
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

I can at least partially answer this - a monotonically changing ID (i.e. incrementing) is HIGHLY DISCOURAGED in Firestore.  The random distribution of those "large ids" is a fundamental performance feature of firestore at scale.  If you need some sort of order, use a field in the document, not the documentID.

Comment: Ok I wanna use field id then. how to increment that for each new document created?

Comment: Not to be mean, but StackOverflow is *not* a tutorial site; it is for answering actual questions of actual problems.  Read the documentation, try something; keep track of the errors and come back with a new , *specific* question.

Comment: i found the solution just this moment, imma show u stackoverflow can help many, just watch;)